# Implementing functional design of a computer system into physical hardware

Tags: computer-architecture

I have recently started studying computer organisation and found that in most of the books the design of computer system is not discussed beyond functional design abstraction level (as shown in the figure)

I want to know what is the procedure to physically implement functional design of a entire computer system (cpu+memory+I/O+system bus) into actual hardware (PCB)?

Fig. functional design of a computer (just for illustrative purpose)

[image]

Comment: In case someone doesn't see the small notice at the top of the page, this question was [merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question) with a previous exact copy: "[Functional design implementation of computer system into actual physical hardware](/questions/622460)". Any further activity should be done there, not here.